# Show the menu at the center of the data toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success open">      
    <i class="icon-comment"></i>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        About the Library                                         
    </a>                                        
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Library Hours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Board of Visitors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Department and Staff</a></li>                    
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Direction Maps</a></li>                    
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Floor Plans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Information and Policies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Mission and Vision</a></li>
    </ul>    
</button>
```

Here's my only CSS Code:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a
{
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #0C6A13;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I have a button with a label "About the Library" as my data toggle. When I click my data toggle, the menu always show in the left side. I want it to be displayed in the center. How will I do it? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can't do anything without the CSS..as mentioned, a JSfiddle.net demo would be useful.

Comment: This is what I got from JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xmo6r7jb/
What is it exactly that you want? The markup is not clear. Why is everything inside a button element?

Comment: @Narxx, --> I've edited my post and included an image. All I wanted is to make my dropdown at the center not on the left side.

Comment: @Paulie_D, --> I've edited my post and included an image. All I wanted is to make my dropdown at the center not on the left side.

Comment: @Benjamin,--> I've edited my post and included an image. All I wanted is to make my dropdown at the center not on the left side.

Comment: There is not enough CSS to diagnose the issue. How are you positioning the menu?

Comment: So the question is basically how to center elements... There are a few ways in which you can achieve that. How is that menu element positioned? static / relative / absolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is a way but you've to specify a width:*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/79wWifpDzR

**Css**:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a
{
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #0C6A13;
}

.dropdown-menu{
 left:0 !important;
 right:0 !important;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    width: 200px;    
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success open dropdown">      
    <i class="icon-comment"></i>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        About the Library                                         
    </a>                                        
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Library Hours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Board of Visitors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Department and Staff</a></li>                    
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Direction Maps</a></li>                    
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Floor Plans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Information and Policies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Mission and Vision</a></li>
    </ul>    
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for the css,

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a
{
background-image: none;
background-color: #0C6A13;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:250px;

}
```

else replace `auto;` with a value for example `margin-left:50px;`

let me know how it goes :)